# Converting geojson::Geometry to geo::Geometry

Tags: rust, geometry, gis, geojson, geo

I have the following code:

```rust
for geometry in geometries.iter() {
    let component = build_bevy_meshes(
        geometry.unwrap().into(),
        Color::Rgba {
            red: (0.),
            green: (0.),
            blue: (0.),
            alpha: (0.),
        },
        BuildBevyMeshesContext::new(),
    );
}
```

Where geometries is a `Vec<Option<geojson::Geometry>>` that I got from a geojson file.

But I'm getting the following error on geometry.unwrap.into():

```
the trait `~const Into<_>` is not implemented for `geojson::Geometry`
```

How Can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`impl<T> TryFrom<Geometry> for Geometry<T>`](https://docs.rs/geojson/latest/geojson/struct.Geometry.html#impl-TryFrom%3CGeometry%3E-for-Geometry%3CT%3E) but have to enable the `geo-types` feature on the `geojson` crate:

```rust
    geometry.unwrap().try_into().unwrap()
```

in Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
geojson = { version = "*", features = ["geo-types"] }
```

Comment: I need to add to your solution the & keyword before geometry.... Now I have the following error cannot infer type of the type parameter `G` declared on the function `build_bevy_meshes' because the method have the following type: Result<impl Iterator<Item = PreparedMesh>, <G as BuildBevyMeshes>::Error>

Comment: Try to solve your problem, if you have done your due diligence (see [ask]) and can't find a solution post a new question with a [mre].